# Is it possible to make a django_filters.AllValuesFilter with choices subject to a given queryset

Tags: django, django-filter

I have a model like this one:

```
class Worker(models.Model):
  city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And the following filter:

```
class CityFilter(django_filters.AllValuesFilter):

    @property
    def field(self):
        f = super(WorkerFilter, self).field
        f.choices = [('', '--------')] +  [(a.pk, a.city) for a in Worker.objects.all()]
        return f


class WorkerFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
  city = ActuallyAllValuesFilter()
  class Meta:
    model = Worker
    fields = ['city']
```

I want to create an AllValuesFilter but whit choices subject to a given queryset instead of all possible values. I mean, I am looking for something like that:

```
class CityFilter(django_filters.AllValuesFilter):

    @property
    def field(self, qs):
        f = super(WorkerFilter, self).field
        f.choices = [('', '--------')] +  [(a.pk, a.city) for a in qs]
        return f
```

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what queryset you're expecting to use, but I can see two possibilities:

#### 1. Use the initial queryset provided to the filterset.

```py
class CityFilter(django_filters.ChoiceFilter):

    @property
    def field(self):
        self.extra['choices'] = [(a.city, a.city) for a in self.parent.queryset]
        return super(CityFilter, self).field

class WorkerFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    city = CityFilter(field_name='city')

    class Meta:
        model = Worker
        fields = ['city']
```

Note that a filter has access to its `parent` filterset after the filterset has been instantiated. `self.parent.queryset` is the *initial* queryset provided to the filterset.

Additionally, it's not necessary to use `AllValuesFilter` in this case as you're discarding the choices that it generates. Inherit from `ChoiceFilter` instead.

#### 2. Provide a queryset to the filter instance.

```py
class CityFilter(django_filters.ChoiceFilter):

    def __init__(self, *args, queryset, **kwargs):
        workers = kwargs.pop('workers', None)

        kwargs['choices'] = [(a.city, a.city) for a in workers]
        super(CityFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class WorkerFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    city = CityFilter(field_name='city', workers=Worker.objects.filter(...))

    class Meta:
        model = Worker
        fields = ['city']
```

Comment: I was looking for something exactly like to your first suggestion but the second one will be usefull for me someday. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: So self.parent.queryset is the initial queryset provided to the filterset, how to get current queryset, one that is already filtered with another filed. For example there was choice `states` after state is selected show only cities in that state?